# Drupal count of nodes by type and date?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to display the total count of one day for a specific node type"

```
function bootstrap_subtheme_get_node_count($content_type) {
     $time = strtotime('yesterday midnight');
     $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) amount FROM {node} n ".
            "WHERE n.type = :type and n.created => " . $time;
     $result = db_query($query, array(':type' => $content_type))->fetch();
     return $result->amount;
}
```

and to print

```
<?php bootstrap_subtheme_get_node_count('page'); ?>
```

Please correct me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I am new developer with limited debug skills. Without this (and n.created => " . $time) above code work fine but count the all nodes. I need node count till last day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks good, please make 2 changes

1: change created as you done with type.

2: remove * symbol from count(*) and put nid or other column name as you like, it is good for query performance.

Code example:

```
function bootstrap_subtheme_get_node_count($content_type) {
     $time = strtotime('yesterday midnight');
     $query = "SELECT COUNT(nid) amount FROM {node} n ".
              "WHERE n.type = :type and n.created => :created";
     $result = db_query($query, array(':type' => $content_type,
                                      ':created' => $time))->fetch();
     return $result->amount;
}
```